# Java: Return number added to Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program in which I'm needing to return the number of reviews added to an array. Here is what I have so far.

```
package assignment;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.time.LocalDate;

class Review {
    public String reviewText;
    public int numberOfStars;

    public Review(String reviewText, int numberOfStars) {
        this.reviewText=reviewText;
        this.numberOfStars=numberOfStars;
    }
}
class GameInfo {
    private String title;
    private Review[] reviews = new Review[10];
    // need an array to keep the reviews; I suggest as below, but feel free to use something else
    // your array needs to be able to contain *at least 10* reviews. My tests will not add more than 10 (later we'll see better collections)
    // private Review[] reviews;
    // can add any other fields; for example, one to keep track of how many reviews you actually have (your array may contain up to 10, but at any given time may have way less; even 0)

    public GameInfo(String title) {
        this.title=title;
        this.reviews= reviews;
        // you may want to initialize any other variables you create here
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


    // TODO - adds the review to the 'array' of reviews. You need to keep all reviews in an array
    public void addReview(Review r) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < this.reviews.length && this.reviews[i++] == null);
    if (i < this.reviews.length) this.reviews[i] = r;
}
    // TODO - returns the number of reviews which have been added to this GameInfo
    public int getNumberOfReviews() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.reviews.length; ++i) {
            ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Here is the Unit Test that is executing the  getNumberOfReviews method:

```
public class Grader {

    @Grade(points=10)
    @Test
    public void testGetNumberOfReviews()
    {       
        GameInfo gi=new GameInfo("SomeGame");
        Assert.assertEquals(0,gi.getNumberOfReviews());
        gi.addReview(new Review("cool",5));
        Assert.assertEquals(1,gi.getNumberOfReviews());

        gi.addReview(new Review("terrible",1));
        Assert.assertEquals(2,gi.getNumberOfReviews());
    }

    @Grade(points=15)
    @Test
```

My code compiles, but it is not passing my Unit Test. I will get 15 points if it passes and I'm not getting any points. Please point out what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

My code compiles, but my unit test still fails with the getNumberofReviews Method. Any help as to why?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code? Also why are you counting the number of reviews? You essentially return the length of the array

Comment: You need to re-think `addReview`. It's not doing what it is named.

Comment: Thanks and I'm not using a debugger. I'm very new to Java and I'm still learning. How do I return the length of the array please?

Comment: @cricket_007 it's a static array the length wouldn't help here.

Comment: Please, create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly demonstrates your problem. There are multiple issues with your code and it isn't clear what particular problem you need to solve

Comment: @donkon I'm aware of the problem. I'm trying to point out the mistakes. The for loop just counts the length of the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the *length* of the `reviews` array to determine the actual number of reviews, and this length is always 10 during your unit tests.  Look closely at your code:

```
private Review[] reviews = new Review[10];
```

and then in your `getNumberOfReviews()` method you tally the count based on this length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.reviews.length; ++i) {
    ++count;
}
```

As a result, the apparent number of reviews always appears to be 10, and your unit test assertions fail.

If you insist on using a fixed size array to store reviews (which I don't prefer, I'd rather use an `ArrayList`), then you need to maintain some state, a counter, in your `GameInfo` class which keeps tracks of the actual number of reviews you have placed into the array:

```
class GameInfo {
    private int numReviews = 0;

    public void addReview(Review r) {
        this.reviews[numReviews++] = r;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Update:**

If you wanted to use an `ArrayList` to store your reviews, the skeleton code would look something like this:

```
class GameInfo {
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addReview(Review r) {
        reviews.add(r);
    }

    public int getNumberOfReviews() {
        return reviews.size();
    }
}
```

The advantage of using a Java collection here (in this case `ArrayList`) is many fold.  First, it will grow automatically as you add reviews, and you don't need to worry about this.  Also, if you need to get features, such as the size, this state is part of the collection, so you don't need to keep track of a separate count.

Comment: I don't insist on using fixed size arrays to store reviews. Could you please share with my your method? Thanks again

Comment: @rls1982 Your code contains *later we'll see better collections*... Probably best to wait until you learn about Arraylists

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen I appreciate it very much

Comment: When I compile I get the following error:
 error: cannot find symbol
        private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Couple problems. You're always returning the length of the array, not the number of reviews.

When you initialize the array, you have 10 null elements. The goal of the question is to skip over the array to find the first non null element and set it.

Then, you already have a Review object, so you just set it to the array position, not make a `new Review` again within the method.

For example, use the while loop to update the position where to place the data. Once that point is reached, you're either at the end of the list, or in the middle. You'll get an exception if the list is full, so you can check for that.

```
public void addReview(Review r) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < this.reviews.length && this.reviews[i++] == null);
    if (i < this.reviews.length) this.reviews[i] = r;
}
```

Same concept can be used to find the "length" of the non null elements in the array, which is the true number of reviews

Comment: This code threw 2 errors
error: cannot find symbol
            if (i < this.reviews.length()) this.reviews[i] = r;

Comment: Which symbol can't be found? `reviews` is defined in your class already.

Comment: It resolved. Sorry I'm late. Any help on the     public int getNumberOfReviews() { method?

Comment: Since you've already accepted an answer, you should put some attempt into the problem with the knowledge gained here, then if you are stuck, you can create a new post

Comment: I have and I think I've found a solution. I've submitted my assignment and I will find out soon